# Unexpected problem opening multiple specific web pages with PowerShell Console / ISE

Tags: powershell, google-chrome, automation

Quick background on the issue:

I'm studying PowerShell, and with some of what I've learned I'm trying to help automate the set-up for my learning process via a script.

While I'm studying I'll have all on one screen:

Two Chrome Windows

One in the background with a specific Google Docs file for my daily schedule, a specific Google Timer for 50 minutes, and a specific Google Sheets file I use to track hours spent studying / working.

In the foreground I'll have a specific YouTube Video Lecture a Google Docs file for notes on that specific programming language (There's several, but in this case PowerShell)

[screenshot link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3F28.png)

The core problem:

The main issue I'm having is that it doesn't seem to be opening in a new window and is instead opening a new tab. All my efforts indicate that the code is correct, but evidently not.

Here's the code:

```
Start-Process -FilePath 'C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\Chrome.exe' -ArgumentList '--newwindow Google Docs URL'
```

It's been a day or two since I've been working on this, but I could've sworn it was working appropriately before. All my Googling efforts seem to indicate that this should be the appropriate code.

The tab will open appropriately, and thus, is not a problem with the URL as I expected to be possible. I get the same problem in both the PowerShell console and ISE.

Comment: Welcome to SO! 
I tried this and it worked, well almost! If chrome was not open it would open chrome to the provided URL (docs file). If chrome was open it would add it as a new tab. This is because I have chrome set to open new items as TABS not Windows. You do not state if it is adding a tab to an existing chrome instance or not. Worth checking into.

Comment: Did you check Task Manager to see if new process was started?  The process may already be running.  I would kill all chrome processes from task manager and then try again.   When you first start a computer windows will automatically restart processes that were running from last time you ran the computer.  This sound like a process that was never stopped when you last ram the computer.  Manually stopping all chrome processes may solve issue.

Comment: The option name is `--new-window`, not `--newwindow` If that solves your problem, we can close your question as a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72104301/45375).

Comment: @mklement0 This is exactly what it was. Oof.

Comment: Glad to hear the solution was so simple; I've closed your question as a duplicate.